# Using dc.js on nested JSON to create bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to create a bar chart for the roles by their count using  dc.js and crossfilter. Need to deal with nested JSON.

Sample data set

```
 [      {  "user":"Mani"
            "age":55,
            "area":"NORTH",
            "role": [
                {
                    "roleId": 15,
                    "role": "Operator",
                    "at": "2018-10-30T07:53:10.433Z",
                    "createdAt": "2018-10-30T07:53:10.449Z"

                },
                {
                    "statusId": 16,
                    "status": "Supervisor",
                    "at": "2018-10-30T07:53:18.359Z",
                    "createdAt": "2018-10-30T07:53:18.359Z"

                },
                {
                    "statusId": 26,
                    "status": "Manager",
                    "at": "2018-10-30T13:01:50.296Z",
                    "createdAt": "2018-10-30T13:01:50.296Z"

                }
                ]
        },  {
            "user":"Kandan"
            "age":65,
             "area":"SOUTH",
            "role": [
                {
                    "roleId": 15,
                    "role": "Operator",
                    "at": "2018-10-30T07:53:10.433Z",
                    "createdAt": "2018-10-30T07:53:10.449Z"

                },
                {
                    "statusId": 16,
                    "status": "Supervisor",
                    "at": "2018-10-30T07:53:18.359Z",
                    "createdAt": "2018-10-30T07:53:18.359Z"

                }
                ]
        }
]
```

I tried creating a chart by using values from the root level of each user but when I tried accessing the `role` key I am somehow able to use only one role not all the roles on other hand it returns the array to the dimension. The basic idea is to have role.role under x-axis and their count on the y-axis. How do I achieve this?

Sample output

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem isn't really the nested JSON; it's the fact that you have multiple roles for each user.

To fetch the roles for each user, you can use an accessor which returns an array of role names:

```
var roleDimension = cf.dimension(d => d.role.map(r => r.role), true);
```

The second parameter specifies that you want a ["tag" or "array" dimension](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_with_arrays). This is a special mode where each row will be counted multiple times, once for each tag in the array which the dimension key accessor returns.

I see you want to use this for a bar chart, which is good - [don't use this for any chart which implicitly adds up to 100%!](https://www.nbcchicago.com/news/local/FOX-News-Chart-Fails-Math-73711092.html) Since the categories are not mutually exclusive, the behavior can be confusing even when you are careful not to imply 100%.

Comment: Thank you so much I managed to create a bar chart. Now it turns out to be a problem with the filter. When the bars are selected it says point.map is not a function it filters certain chart but not all the charts on the screen.

Comment: I don't think you need any more steps for the "tag dimension" and this bar chart. Sounds like you are running into a new, unrelated problem with your scatter plot definition now. (It helps to look at the source of the error.) Maybe the dimension/group for your scatter plot is not producing arrays of size 2 (points)? Remember, you only want to use the second argument to `crossfilter.dimension` when your key function returns multiple values - you probably don't want it for your scatter plot dimension.

Comment: Feel free to open another question if you can't figure it out. I consider this question answered.

Comment: Yes, sir. That issue got resolved, my code had some issue.